# How to get the union/merge of dictionaries?

Tags: vimscript, dictionary

I'd like to combine two nested dictionaries following these rules:

- if value is not a dictionary, override the key in resulting dictionary
- if value is a dictionary, compute union of the two.

Example:

```
dic1 = {'nest': {'foo': '42', 'same_key': 'a'}, 'same_key2': {'k1': 'v1'}}
dic2 = {'nest': {'bar': '43', 'same_key': 'b'}, 'same_key2': {'k2': 'v2'}}

dic1+dic2:

{'nest': {'foo': '42', 'bar': '43', 'same_key': 'b'}, 'same_key2': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2', 'v2'}}
```

This [solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20842/how-can-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-vim) overrides the key and does not do the union part.

Comment: You have to define “union” somehow.

Comment: have you tried the different modes of `extend()`?

Comment: yes, 'force' and 'keep' just prioritize which dictionary's values will remain in the extended result. I modified the function in the linked solution and it worked for couple of tests I did. Feedback on my changes (below) is appreciated to iron out issues with it

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using to achieve the example described in my question.
Any improvements?

```vim
" Merge two dictionaries, also recursively combining nested keys.
" Otherwise 'override' takes priority.

function! g:MyMerge(defaults, override) abort
  let l:new = a:defaults
  for [l:k, l:v] in items(a:override)
    if type(get(l:new, l:k)) is v:t_dict && type(l:v) is v:t_dict
      call g:MyMerge(l:new[l:k], l:v)
    else
      let l:new[l:k] = l:v
    endif
  endfor
  return l:new
endfun
```

Comment: "Any improvements?" Just one nitpick: I think the `g:` is redundant and you don't need to use it here you could just create `function! MyMerge...` but that's a detail.